# SQL 3 table Join While taking all values from 1 table but only filled from other 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables: the first has a list of category IDs, the second has dataset information, and the third has import information.

What I have

```
select dataset.pc_id , count(*) 
from import 
join dataset on CAST (dataset.internal_id as varchar(20)) = import.product_id 
group by dataset.pc_id,  order by pc_id asc
```

This will output:

```
3 4

4 5

6 200

7 192

8 1000
```

Where `product_category` comes into play is this:  I want the output to look like:

```
1 0

2 0

3 4

4 5

6 200

...

16 0
```

The 16 are the number of different product categories from the `product_category` table that I currently cannot figure out how to fit into that statement.

What is the way to get all the id's from product category into this list with the information joined occupying the result?

Comment: There are a lot of questions already about using a left join

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to get rid of selecting dataset.pc_id and just go with product_category.id and then right join product_category.